# What do these train codes on Paris RER B (airports subway line) mean?

Tags: trains, france, paris, ratp

While standing on the platform waiting for the RER B train to Charles de Gaulle airport in Paris, I noticed codes like **ELOT** or **EPEX** besides arrival time, platform number, destination, etc.

**What do these codes mean?**

I didn't see any information in the station. RER B has two types of trains, one that stops at every station on the way and an express one that stops at a few stations (Gare du Nord, etc) before Charles de Gaulle airport. Can express trains be distinguished from these codes?

Note: the codes above are given as examples. Not sure they are accurate as I do this out of memory a few days after traveling in Paris. The second one I saw ended in EX but was not an express train.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These train codes are called mission codes.

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligne_B_du_RER_d%27%C3%8Ele-de-France, via [Gtranslate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=fr&tl=en&text=Premi%C3%A8re%20lettre%20(destination%20du%20train)%0ALa%20premi%C3%A8re%20lettre%20renseigne%20sur%20la%20destination%20finale%20du%20train%20prenant%20des%20voyageurs%2C%20selon%20les%20deux%20tableaux%20ci-dessus.%0ADeuxi%C3%A8me%20lettre%20(desserte)%0ALa%20deuxi%C3%A8me%20lettre%20s%27associe%20%C3%A0%20la%20premi%C3%A8re%20pour%20d%C3%A9tailler%20les%20gares%20desservies%20par%20le%20train.%0ATroisi%C3%A8me%20et%20quatri%C3%A8me%20lettres%0AElles%20sont%20choisies%20pour%20rendre%20le%20tout%20pronon%C3%A7able%20et%20m%C3%A9morisable&op=translate)

- First letter (train destination): The first letter provides information on the final destination of the train, according to the two tables below.
- Second letter (serving): The second letter indicates the stations served by the train.
- Third and fourth letters: They are chosen to make everything pronounceable and memorable.

---

Meaning of first letter used regularly:

| Letter | Destination |
| --- | --- |
| E | [Aéroport Charles-de-Gaulle 2 TGV](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gare_de_l%27a%C3%A9roport_Charles-de-Gaulle_2_TGV&action=edit&redlink=1) |
| I | [Mitry - Claye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Mitry_-_Claye) |
| J | [Denfert-Rochereau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Denfert-Rochereau) |
| K | [Massy - Palaiseau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Massy_-_Palaiseau) |
| L | [Orsay-Ville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_d%27Orsay-Ville) |
| P | [Saint-Rémy-lès-Chevreuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Saint-R%C3%A9my-l%C3%A8s-Chevreuse) |
| Q | [La Plaine - Stade de France](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gare_de_La_Plaine_-_Stade_de_France&action=edit&redlink=1) |
| S | [Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Robinson) |
| U | [Laplace](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gare_de_Laplace&action=edit&redlink=1) |

Meaning of first letter used exceptionally:

| Letter | Destination |
| --- | --- |
| A | [Gare du Nord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Paris-Nord) |
| G | [Aulnay-sous-Bois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_d%27Aulnay-sous-Bois) |
| H | [Bourg-la-Reine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Bourg-la-Reine) |
| M | [Châtelet - Les Halles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Ch%C3%A2telet_-_Les_Halles) |
| V | [Lozère](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Loz%C3%A8re) |
| X | [Parc des Expositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_du_Parc_des_Expositions) |
| Y | [Les Baconnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_des_Baconnets) |

All codes from a few years ago: http://michou94.free.fr/html/missiona.html.

Answer (score 10):

**The 4-letters codes describe the different routes and types of trains (express or not) of the RER B line**. Indeed, RER B forks at Aulnay-sous-Bois station (while traveling to the North-East part of Paris suburb) with the B3 route going to Charles-de-Gaulle airport and the B5 route going to Mitry-Claye station. It also forks in the opposite direction at Bourg-la-Reine station with the B4 route going to Saint-Remy-les-Chevreuses.

This [article](https://francetravelplanner.com/go/paris/trans/air/choose-rer-b-train-cdg-airport-to-paris.html) describes it:

> The fastest trains from CDG to central Paris have route codes beginning with KA (KALE, KALI, KAPE, KARE, etc.) or JA (JAMI, JANO), or UL. Other trains make more stops.

> For your return to CDG airport from central Paris, look for B3 trains with route codes beginning with E, because all trains beginning with E go to CDG. The express trains are ERIC, EROC, ERIO, ERSE, EDME [,or] EDDY.

Here is a picture from the same article (direction CDG - Central Paris)

[image: Pictures from the link above]

It seems that JIBY train stops at Denfert-Rochereau and does not go all the way, in particular not stopping at Antony (near Orly airport) and KDIT stops on the B4 route at Massy-Palaiseau.

Additional details in this [article](https://francetravelplanner.com/go/paris/trans/ratp/rer/riding.html)